# How to pass a variable to urls.py

Tags: regex, django, url

I have a database 'artist' with one table : 'name', 'style'.
Users can add any names for an artist.

I would like to pass an argument to url in my template, like this :

```
<a href="{% url 'webgui.views.music' artist.name %}" style="margin-bottom: 3px" type="button"
```

But is it possible to set dynamically the URL with the argument 'artist.name' (in urls.py) ?

My urls.py actually :

```
url(r'^music/(\d+)/$', 'webgui.views.music'),
```

Maybe I need to change '\d+' by another regexp ??

Comment: you want to use a variable to select the named url? eg a variable containing `'webgui.views.music'` ?

Comment: according to docs that is possible https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Comment: No. Like this in Django URLs doc : `url(r'^articles/(?P<year>\d{4})/$', 'news.views.year_archive'),` , except I don't know the length variable..  Thanks for the link.

Comment: I don't understand what is your question... are you just trying to work out the correct regex in the url for accepting an artist name?

Comment: This is very unclear. artist.name is already a variable. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using

```
url(r'^music/(\d+)/$', 'webgui.views.music'),
```

because **d+** stands for digits, you should use

```
url(r'^music/?P<artist_name>[a-zA-Z0-9 \'&-]/$', 'webgui.views.music')
```

Don't forget to modify function

```
def whatever_named_it(request, artist_name):
    ...
```

**Update:** In template you should use

```
{% url 'webgui.views.music' artist_name=artist.name %}
```

because we are using named arguments.

**Extra**: If you are going to allow any text for artist's name, I would recommend you using [slug](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/glossary/) to avoid spaces in URL. That would make it better to read, search engine friendly and avoid of insane user input. When programming web-app never trust user input ... ever.

For "slugified" name urls would be:

```
url(r'^music/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', 'webgui.views.music')
```

Comment: `[a-zA-Z0-9 \'&-]` is extremely ethnocentric as a regular expression to capture names.

Comment: Thank you, gcerar, it was about I've asked.  But it doesn't works (NoReverseMatch), and I'm not sure it will be my final solution.

Comment: Isador, can you try url(r'^music/(?P<artist_name>[a-zA-Z0-9 \'&-])/$', 'webgui.views.music') instead and report if it's working?

Comment: The same : `Exception Value:  

Reverse for 'webgui.views.music' with arguments '(u'Anathema',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ["music/(?P<artist_name>[a-zA-Z0-9 \\'&-])/$"]`

Comment: Ooooh right. Sorry I forgot we used named argument. In template replace {% url 'webgui.views.music' artist.name %} with {% url 'webgui.views.music' artist_name=artist.name %}. I think that should do it.